# How to delete a project in QGIS

Tags: qgis, delete, qgs

Somehow I've created two projects with duplicate data in QGIS. How can I delete one of them?

Comment: Do you want to know how to delete a file or how to remove a table from a QGIS project?

Answer (score 2):

A QGIS project is a single .qgs file. All the other data (.shp files, databases...) is simply linked by this .qgs file.

The process therefore depends on how your data structure looks. If you have two .qgs project files which point to the *same* data, you can simply delete the .qgs file.

If you have two .qgs files, each with their own copy of the linked data, you will want to delete all of the relevant files.

To check if the data is duplicate you can go to the layer properties and compare the "Layer Source" in the tab "General".